# Construct JSON to be used with slackNotification plugin for Jenkins

Tags: arrays, json, jenkins, groovy, slack

Given the below JSON example (from Slack website), I have tried many ways to construct that message. I tried `net.sf.json.JSONObject` and `net.sf.json.JSONArray`.  But I can't get it done correctly.

I interpret to object as :

1 `net.sf.json.JSONObject` with 1 key-value-pair 'attachment' = array

1 `net.sf.json.JSONArray.1` with hashmap as fields

1 of the fields value is ref to `net.sf.json.JSONArray.2`

A `net.sf.json.JSONArray.2` that consist 1 element

This element is another nested `net.sf.json.JSONObject`

What am I doing wrong ? I am not attaching code examples, since I tried many times and realize that probably I am doing something wrong.

```
{
"attachments": [
    {
        "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
        "color": "#36a64f",
        "pretext": "Optional text that appears above the attachment block",
        "author_name": "Bobby Tables",
        "author_link": "http://flickr.com/bobby/",
        "author_icon": "http://flickr.com/icons/bobby.jpg",
        "title": "Slack API Documentation",
        "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/",
        "text": "Optional text that appears within the attachment",
        "fields": [
            {
                "title": "Priority",
                "value": "High",
                "short": false
            }
        ],
        "image_url": "http://my-website.com/path/to/image.jpg",
        "thumb_url": "http://example.com/path/to/thumb.png",
        "footer": "Slack API",
        "footer_icon": "https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/default_application_icon.png",
        "ts": 123456789
    }
]
}
```

Comment: chenchuk, please check the solution to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This Jenkinsfile works:

```
#!/bin/groovy

node ('mynode') {
    stage ("Build") {
        def attachments = """[ { \"text\": \"And here’s an attachment!\" } ]"""
        echo (attachments)
        slackSend (channel: "@rolf", color: "danger", message: "Test message", attachments: attachments)
    }
}
```

This does not:

```
#!/bin/groovy

node ('mynode') {
    stage ("Build") {
        def attachments = """
[ { \"text\": \"And here’s an attachment!\" } ]"""
        echo (attachments)
        slackSend (channel: "@rolf", color: "danger", message: "Test message", attachments: attachments)
    }
}
```

So the answer is: make sure the attachments string does not start with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it using below simple script:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
json {
    attachments ([ 
        {
            fallback 'Required plain-text summary of the attachment.'
            color '#36a64f'
            pretext 'Optional text that appears above the attachment block'
            author_name 'Bobby Tables'
            author_link 'http://flickr.com/bobby/'
            author_icon 'http://flickr.com/icons/bobby.jpg'
            title 'Slack API Documentation'
            title_link 'https://api.slack.com/'
            text 'Optional text that appears within the attachment'
            fields([
                {
                            title 'Priority'
                            value 'High'
                            'short' false
                }
            ])
            image_url 'http://my-website.com/path/to/image.jpg'
            thumb_url 'http://example.com/path/to/thumb.png'
            footer 'Slack API'
            footer_icon 'https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/default_application_icon.png'
            ts 123456789
        }

    ])
}
println json.toPrettyString()
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/GfITSy)</kbd>

Comment: I get this : ERROR: Slack notification failed with exception: net.sf.json.JSONException: Invalid JSON String. I guess its a different types, can i somehow covert this json to net.sf.json ? im using this step in jenkins pipeline :             slackSend(color: '#A9FF55', channel: 'jenkinsdebug', attachments: json.toString())
because this is the way it appears on the slack plugin page example in github

Comment: Have you tried online demo? By the way the above solution does not use specified class, so no way you can get the mentioned exception.

Comment: Are you getting the mentioned exception when you the above solution as is? Or have tried it at least? If not then appreciate if you can give it try.

Comment: i have a strange behavior. if im using your code inside the jenkins pipeline, the first line interpreted as 1 statement, then the next one interpret the 'json' as a command and it throws 'json is unknown step ...' so i add "=" to the 2nd line which is now : json = {.....}, then is get the  error from the slack plugin : 15:21:51 ERROR: Slack notification failed with exception: net.sf.json.JSONException: Invalid JSON String

Comment: i know its not related to the question, but here is an example from github plugin page, it uses toString of net.sf.json.JSONArray to send 
 the notification: https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin

Comment: Please go thru earlier comments. Hope you tried demo at least.

Comment: im sorry that u got the feeling that i didnt try the offered solution, indeed i open the demo page and copy/paste your code into a stage block in jenkins pipeline dsl (is there something else i miss in the demo ?). then i run the job and got a runtime error when parsing the pipeline steps, so i add the '=' sign at row #2 (ie. json={  ) which i guess is the groovy way to assign the {} to the json ref. am i doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Did it work as desired when you tried the demo? No idea about Jenkins.